# Sqllite query on distinct or certain value

Tags: sqlite, distinct

I have an android sqllite database. It has a text column called chainid.

I'd like to return all columns from rows with DISTINCT chainids || or where chainid is equal to: "none".

So e.g.:

| ID| Name        | chainid |
| 1 | widgetname1 | 12345   |
| 2 | widgetname2 | 12345   |
| 3 | widgetname3 | "none"  |
| 4 | widgetname4 | 49390   |
| 5 | widgetname5 | 49390   |

Given the above table I would like my query to return 3 rows with all columns for row 2, row3 and row5. -- So DISTINCT on chainid OR where chainid = "none" with the max id selected as the distinct row

Can I achieve this in one query?

I could return all and then process afterwards in java, but this is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
select *
from table where id in
( select max(id)
  from table
  group by chainid
  where chainid != 'none'
  union
  select id
  from table
  where chainid = 'none'
)
```

Comment: The problem with that query is that it will group the chainids where the chainid is "none" - I want distinct chainids where the value is not none, and ALL chainids = "none".

Comment: ok, then

     ...
    group by chainid where chainid != 'none'
    union select id from table where chainid = 'none'
    )